# In Git, how do I figure out what my current revision is?

Tags: git

I just want to know what my current revision number is.

Comment: I found this question while I was looking for a way to get the current revision in order to use it in further git commands. But when I read the answers, I figured it out: "Oh wait, I don't need it, I can just use `HEAD` actually."

Answer (score 293, accepted):

What do you mean by "version number"?  It is quite common to tag a commit with a version number and then use

```
$ git describe --tags
```

to identify the current HEAD w.r.t. any tags.  If you mean you want to know the hash of the current HEAD, you probably want:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
```

or for the short revision hash:

```
$ git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

It is often sufficient to do:

```
$ cat .git/refs/heads/${branch-main}
```

but this is not reliable as the ref may be packed.

Comment: Refs may be packed in `.git/packed-refs`, so you should probably avoid directly accessing `.git/refs/`. Just use `git rev-parse master` (or `git rev-parse refs/heads/master` if you need to be completely unambiguous).

Comment: `git describe` is what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 126):

There are many ways `git log -1` is the easiest and most common, I think

Comment: How do I make a file become a previous version?

Comment: maybe you want git checkout HEAD^ -- filename

Comment: btw, this gives A LOT MORE than just current revision and you'll have to parse it consequently (so, not the best/easiest/common solution, imho)

Comment: I am really confused: if I use `git log -1` I see the hash number but also the current git tag:
    git log -1
    commit 555f2ab5d8bfe06d7ab17e87b6c331ef6a735fd9 (HEAD -> main, tag: mytag-01)
    Author: xx xx  <xxxxx@xxx.xx>
    Date:   Fri Jan 7 17:53:22 2022 +0100

but if I grep it for the first line with word `commit` I only get the hash?  
    git log -1| grep commit
    commit 555f2ab5d8bfe06d7ab17e87b6c331ef6a735fd9

Comment: It was useful to add option ` --decorate`, so that the string `(HEAD -> main, tag: mytag-01)` was also output if I piped the result to another shell command, e.g.
    git log -1 --decorate | grep commit  # first line with tag string added

Answer (score 49):

This gives you just the revision.

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

Comment: I think that this is the best answer, since it is not implementation-dependent. William's answer "cat .git/refs/heads/master" will provide the same value, but there's no guarantee that it will work in the future if the implementation changes.

Comment: Agreed, this is the best answer. A brief mention of the `--short` option would make it perfect.

Answer (score 19):

This gives you the first few digits of the hash and they are unique enough to use as say a version number.

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

Answer (score 4):

below will work with any previously pushed revision, not only HEAD

for abbreviated revision hash:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:%h
```

for long revision hash:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:%H
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple way to output the current commit that includes the version number, I use:

```
git show $(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

From there I can parse the output as required.