# Can gnu-make save git-version of the compiled code?

Tags: git, gnu-make

At the moment I am manually saving each compiled executable together with the git-hash of the source code. I want to find a better/automatized way to create, with each compilation using gnu-make a file storing the git-hash.

Would this in any way be possible or is there another common practice to tackle this problem?

Comment: You can use any of the options in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5724755/14660

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's not very clear, how exactly you want to store the compilation result. If you have it in mind, please specify it. If not, we may come dangerously close to a recommendation question which is prohibited on SO, and (psst) you may take a look at [Conan](https://conan.io/).